# ACF auto complete all value from 1 cpt to another cpt

Tags: custom-field

I want to fill all values in CPT 2 automatically if field names match between CPT 2 and CPT 1. In cases where, for instance, CPT 2 field 1 doesn't match CPT 1 field 1, manual input for all fields in CPT 2 becomes necessary. Can anyone help me, I'm very new to ACF ...

```
CPT 1
Field 1 (text field)
Field 2 (text field)
Field 3 (text field)
Field 4 (number field)
Field 5 (text field)

CPT 2
Field 1 (select field ajax)
Field 2 (text field)
Field 3 (text field)
Field 4 (number field)
Field 5 (text field)
```

I will donate to you for the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

To automatically populate the values of CPT 2 fields from CPT 1 when their field names match, you can achieve this using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) and some custom code. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do it:

1. Install and Activate ACF: Make sure you have ACF installed and activated on your WordPress site.
2. Create Fields in CPT 1 and CPT 2: Create the necessary custom fields in both CPT 1 and CPT 2 as described in your question.
3. Write Custom PHP Code:

```php
function populate_cpt2_fields_from_cpt1($post_id) {
    if (get_post_type($post_id) === 'cpt1') {
        // Get the current CPT 1 post
        $cpt1_post = get_post($post_id);

        // Get the field values of CPT 1
        $field1_value = get_field('field_1', $cpt1_post);
        $field2_value = get_field('field_2', $cpt1_post);
        $field3_value = get_field('field_3', $cpt1_post);
        $field4_value = get_field('field_4', $cpt1_post);
        $field5_value = get_field('field_5', $cpt1_post);

        // Get the corresponding CPT 2 post
        $cpt2_post = get_page_by_title($cpt1_post->post_title, OBJECT, 'cpt2');

        if ($cpt2_post) {
            // Update the fields in CPT 2 if they exist and match CPT 1 field names
            update_field('field_1', $field1_value, $cpt2_post->ID);
            update_field('field_2', $field2_value, $cpt2_post->ID);
            update_field('field_3', $field3_value, $cpt2_post->ID);
            update_field('field_4', $field4_value, $cpt2_post->ID);
            update_field('field_5', $field5_value, $cpt2_post->ID);
        }
    }
}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'populate_cpt2_fields_from_cpt1', 20);
```

Replace `'cpt1'` and `'cpt2'` with the actual slugs of your CPT 1 and CPT 2.

4. How It Works:

   - The code above hooks into the ACF `acf/save_post` action.
   - It checks if the saved post is of type CPT 1.
   - If it is, it retrieves the field values of CPT 1.
   - It then looks for a CPT 2 post with the same title as CPT 1 (assuming titles match).
   - If a CPT 2 post is found, it updates the fields in CPT 2 with the values from CPT 1, but only if the field names match.
5. Usage:

   - Whenever you create or update a CPT 1 post, the code will automatically populate the corresponding fields in CPT 2 if they exist and have matching field names.

Remember to test this code on a development/staging site first to ensure it works as expected with your specific setup. You can test the code in `functions.php` within your theme. Also make sure to adjust the CPT slugs and field names to match your actual configuration.